# Scripts for Python are not on PATH

Tags: python, django, path, installation, virtualenv

So I am new to Python (and programming in general) and I am trying to install it on my Mac. Forgive me if I might ask silly questions.

I currently have Python 3.6 and django 2.0 installed with it
- I just installed virtualenv and pipenv which I don't get the difference but my terminal says that those scripts are not on PATH. How do I add those directories to the PATH and how can I check that they are on the right path?

Do I need something more before starting to code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add those directories to your PATH variable. Thus you can use them on shell without writing directories all the time.

echo 'export PATH=YOUR_VIRENV_PATH:$PATH' >> ~/.profile

Comment: Thanks! so I copy this whole line in my terminal including echo?

Comment: yes but you need to write your virtualenv path instead of YOUR_VIRENV_PATH